# What do you call someone who repairs punctures?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term specifically used colloquially or formally to refer to a person who mends punctures in tires of e.g. cars, bicycles, bikes, etc.

Comment: My proposal is a 'parent'?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "tire mechanic" or "tire expert" or "tire repair expert" "the 'Mr. Fixit' of tires" or "puncture repairperson" or "puncture repair specialist" or any number of other multi-word descriptions. I am not aware, however, of a single word for such a person, except a person's name, of course ("See Ron, he's our tire puncture specialist." Also, @MarvMills is onto something with his suggestion of "parent," especially "dad," though I'll be accused of being sexist and non-PC!

Comment: Do you know of a language that has such a word? If so it would be delightful to know about it.

Comment: @WS2 Yeah Persian uses *Aparati* or *Panchari* or *Panchargiri* [derived from *puncture* I guess!]

Comment: @rhetorician Actually I started with 'Dad' and overtyped it :)

Comment: A *flatologist*?

Comment: @bib - I think a *flatologist* might be most likely to study flatulence.

Comment: @AndyT That's a *flatulologist*, as opposed to a *flautologist*, who studies a different kind of tooting.

Comment: @JasonStack How about "tire monkey?"

Comment: The only scenario where a person might be dedicated to such activity is in an auto tire store or large auto repair shop.  Otherwise, the job is handled by a mechanic.  In particular, most bicycle tire repairs are handled by the bike rider, or a family member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the colloquialism, ***tire monkey***.

> monkey: (*slang*) a menial employee who does a repetitive job, as in
>   *code monkey*, *grease monkey*, *phone monkey*, *powder monkey*. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/monkey)

I would assume that the term can be perceived as offensive and/or derogatory, depending on context.

Comment: 'Tire monkey' seems to be used almost entirely for a useful gadget.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK 'puncture repair man' used to be in common use (based on my personal recollection); a quick google search suggests that that phrase is now most common in India.

Comment: Reminds me of 'bicycle repair man', Python's spoof on superheroes.

Comment: Yeah, it used to be a very common construction. I feel like it's less so now - I wonder if it's because of a shift in the language itself or just because we don't have so many people professionally repairing things now?

Comment: I'm over 70, and I've never come across the term before now.